# Inject Service in Provider`s $get method

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two different implementations of a Bluetooth Low Energy service for my angular app.

So i created a generic `bluetoothServiceProvider` which should return the correct implementation of the bluetooth service. One is the `cordovaBluetoothService` the other one is the `chromeBluetoothService`. So i check the `window` properties and decide which one i need.

I know i can inject those two services into the `$get` function like

```
this.$get = [
    'chromeBluetoothService',
    'cordovaBluetoothService',
    function(chromeBtS, cordovaBtS) {
        if(window.cordova) {
            return cordovaBtS;
        else {
            return chromeBtS;
        }
    }
];
```

But this is not optimal since both dependencies get instantiated on injection (i dont want to do feature detection within the implementations), so i want them to be instantiated within the if clause. How do i do this?

I tried:

```
var $injector = angular.injector();
return $injector.get('chromeBluetoothService');
```

but it returns an `Unknown provider: chromeBluetoothServiceProvider <- chromeBluetoothService`

if i do: `var $injector = angular.injector('myApp.services');`

it cannot instantiate the module since this is the config phase still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject your app's `$injector` (so it knows about the services available to your app).
Luckily for us, the `$injector` service knows how to inject itself:

```
this.$get = ['$injector', function ($injector) {
    if (window.cordova) {
        return $injector.get('cordovaBluetoothService');
    else {
        return $injector.get('chromeBluetoothService');
    }
}
```